# Gradle task to download a remote project directory as a zip file and unzip it

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a snapshot of a project which needs to be downloaded into my current project as a zip file using a `Gradle` `task`.

After which, I will unzip it and run some commands to integrate that code into my current application.

How do I create such a Gradle task which can download a remote Nexus directory as a zip and then unzip it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching quite a bit, I found the solution to do it -

```
task downloadZipFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://your-zip-file-url/file.zip'
    dest new File(buildDir, 'new-filename.zip')
}

task downloadAndUnzipFile(dependsOn: downloadZipFile, type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(downloadZipFile.dest)
    into buildDir

}
```

For more such solutions, you can refer to this link - https://michelkraemer.com/recipes-for-gradle-download/